Can I still cash a check that is spelled out one-forty-five and no/100s instead of one hundred forty- five and no/100s with 145 in the number box?
I was given a check that says one - forty-five and no/100s with 145 in the dollar box can I still cash it? is it acceptable?

I tagged this united-states based on my best guess (references to dollars and spelling it check - but that doesn't guarantee I'm right). Check / cheque cashing norms vary in different places, so please edit / comment if you were interested in answers from a different location.

can I still cash it depends on the bank(s) involved, but the duped to question explains why they may reject it.
